# Can I control the 'density' of a pattern in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

...i.e. I want to control the spacing between lines in a hatch pattern. Is that possible at all with the predefined patterns from the `pattern` library, like `north east lines`? Or should I just create my own pattern? I tried the `step` modifier, but it has no effect as in the minimal *non-working* example below. ;)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [step=0.5cm, pattern=north east lines] (0,0) rectangle (1.4,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**EDIT**: I changed the code a bit, because I would like to control the spacing in *any* type of pattern and originally in the example was `grid`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns

Comment: If you are not locked into tikz, you can consider using pstricks with the package [pst-fill](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-fill). This package provides many options to customize the pattern fillsep[x,y], fillangle, fillcycle[x,y] fillmove[x,y].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Gonzalo says the patterns are not customizable.  So, here is one way you can customize the code for the `grid` pattern to accept a variable that allows you to control the density by adjusting the `GridSize=1pt`.  The default is `GridSize=3pt`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\GridSize]{MyGrid}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\GridSize}{\GridSize}}%
{
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.3pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{3.1pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.1pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\newdimen\GridSize
\tikzset{
    GridSize/.code={\GridSize=#1},
    GridSize=3pt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grid/.style={pattern=MyGrid}]
   \draw [GridSize=1pt, pattern=MyGrid] (0,0) rectangle (1.4,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I really want, I'd like to set the spacing for _any_ pattern...

Comment: Ok have updated the solution to provide a way to control the spacing of the `grid`.  This is similar to Gonzalo's solution, but has an extra feature of an adjustable parameter to control the size.

Comment: Peter, is this still true now? I mean, maybe there have been updates of the library. Are we still unable to set the distance beween lines?

Answer (score 19):

The answer of Peter works only for `\GridSize` smaller than `4pt`, if you want to modify the pattern in order to accept all `\GrideSize` you have to use the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\GridSize]{MyGrid}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\GridSize}{\GridSize}}{\pgfqpoint{\GridSize}{\GridSize}}%
{
     \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
     \pgfsetlinewidth{0.3pt}
     \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\GridSize + 0.1pt}}
     \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
     \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\GridSize + 0.1pt}{0pt}}
     \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\newdimen\GridSize
\tikzset{
    GridSize/.code={\GridSize=#1},
    GridSize=3pt
}
```

Then if you want to modify al type of patterns to accept this density option you have to modify all pattern's codes inserting them in your preamble or directly in the file `pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex`. Here there are other two example of such modified patterns:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\LineSpace]{my north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\LineSpace]{my north west lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\LineSpace}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}{-0.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\newdimen\LineSpace
\tikzset{
    line space/.code={\LineSpace=#1},
    line space=3pt
}
```

In any case there is a problem of color specification (see [Modified pattern does not see the pattern color option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119710/modified-pattern-does-not-see-the-pattern-color-option))

Comment: The line pattern generated in this way consists of bunch of dashed-look lines... Is it possible to make them solid lines? I tried to tweak everything free parameters, though nothing helped.

Answer (score 13):

A quick look at the file `pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex` reveals that the predefined patterns do not accept modifications through keys. You will have to create your own pattern, or modify the existing ones to make them key-aware.

The following code shows the definition of a `my grid` (more dense grid) pattern, side by side with the predefined `grid`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{my grid}{\pgfqpoint{-2pt}{-2pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{2pt}{2pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{3.1pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.1pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [step=0.5cm, pattern=my grid] (0,0) rectangle (1.4,1.4);
    \draw [step=0.5cm, pattern=grid] (2,0) rectangle (3.4,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the oritional definition of the `grid` pattern:

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{grid}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{3.1pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.1pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Or you can use `\hatchsep=3pt` or more, so the lines separate more and have less of them.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your suggested solution? Does this work with [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) as in the OP?

Comment: This is not an answer at all. It might be a comment to one of the other answers, but I cannot find `\hatchsep` on this page.