# Custom and built in TikZ fill patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can't find much information about creating TikZ fill patterns or even using the custom built-in patterns. Look to do all the common fills like lines, hatches, dots, stars, etc... I need to be able to control the scale, too. (The patterns I did end up finding were way to large.)

Google doesn't seem to return much info on TikZ fill patterns.

Comment: Refer **chapter 41** of pgf manual on patterns.

Comment: @HarishKumar This gives some(or all?) built in patterns but doesn't describe how to change the scale or create built in ones?

Comment: you may have to look in to the source code of pattern library.

Comment: Refer also to chapter 62 (pgf2.00) or chapter 78 (pgf2.10) to define custom patterns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hatch a rectangle in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz)

Comment: @Altermundus Can you write up an answer from the method [given in your answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz/54471#54471)?

Comment: @percusse Not easy to answer. First the question is not a duplicate of "Hatch a rectangle". You can hatch a rectangle without using a pattern like with my code, then "custom and built a pattern" is for any shape. An answer to the question is to search the macro `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly` inside Tex.SE,  inside the sources of pgf and on the net.

Answer (score 81):

### Customizing an existing pattern

The `fivepointed star` pattern is defined in [`pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex) as

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{fivepointed stars}% name
  {\pgfpointorigin}% bottom left
  {\pgfqpoint{3mm}{3mm}}% top right
  {\pgfqpoint{3mm}{3mm}}% tile size
  {% code
   \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{1mm}{1mm}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpointpolar{18}{1mm}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{162}{1mm}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{306}{1mm}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{90}{1mm}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{234}{1mm}}
   \pgfpathclose%
   \pgfusepath{fill}
  }
```

If you want to change the size of stars or how far away they are of each other, you just need to change the `1mm` and `3mm` values respectively, but you need to define a new pattern for that. If you want full flexibility, you need to define a pattern with variables which you can adjust. Let's say we want the `starsize` and `starspread` parameters to customize the pattern. We first define the lengths:

```
% defining the new dimensions
\newlength{\starsize}
\newlength{\starspread}
```

then declare the corresponding tikz keys:

```
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{starsize/.code={\setlength{\starsize}{#1}},
         starspread/.code={\setlength{\starspread}{#1}}}
```

then set the default values:

```
% setting the default values
\tikzset{starsize=1mm,
         starspread=3mm}
```

and finally declare the pattern itself using our variables:

```
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\starspread,\starsize]% variables
  {custom fivepointed stars}% name
  {\pgfpointorigin}% lower left corner
  {\pgfqpoint{\starspread}{\starspread}}% upper right corner
  {\pgfqpoint{\starspread}{\starspread}}% tilesize
  {% shape description
   \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{\starsize}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpointpolar{18}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{162}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{306}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{90}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{234}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathclose%
   \pgfusepath{fill}
  }
```

You can then just use things like `\draw[pattern=custom fivepointed stars,starspread=1.5mm,starsize=0.5mm] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);` to produce small stars close to each other in a rectangle. Here's the full code:

[image: tikz star patterns examples]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

% defining the new dimensions
\newlength{\starsize}
\newlength{\starspread}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{starsize/.code={\setlength{\starsize}{#1}},
         starspread/.code={\setlength{\starspread}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{starsize=1mm,
         starspread=3mm}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\starspread,\starsize]% variables
  {custom fivepointed stars}% name
  {\pgfpointorigin}% lower left corner
  {\pgfqpoint{\starspread}{\starspread}}% upper right corner
  {\pgfqpoint{\starspread}{\starspread}}% tilesize
  {% shape description
   \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpoint{\starsize}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpointpolar{18}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{162}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{306}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{90}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{234}{\starsize}}
   \pgfpathclose%
   \pgfusepath{fill}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=fivepointed stars] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=custom fivepointed stars,starspread=5mm] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=custom fivepointed stars,starspread=5mm,starsize=2mm] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=custom fivepointed stars,starspread=1.5mm,starsize=0.5mm] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In the same vein, you can customize hatch lines. Here's the code for north west lines. I've put options for color and shifting the hatch lines up (not down):

[image: tikz hatch pattern which can be colored]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=3pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=0pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north west lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=6pt,hatchthickness=1pt,hatchcolor=red] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=10pt,hatchthickness=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}% hatchshift must be >= 0
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=10pt,hatchcolor=red] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=10pt,hatchcolor=blue,hatchshift=2.5pt] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=10pt,hatchcolor=green!65!black,hatchshift=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=10pt,hatchcolor=violet,hatchshift=7.5pt] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here's the code for north east lines:

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north east lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchshift-0.15pt}{-0.15pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread-\hatchshift+0.15pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.15pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread-\hatchshift-0.15pt}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchshift+0.15pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }
```

### Creating new patterns

Creating new patterns is a bit more complex and needs choosing the right shape, the bounding box overlapping, etc. You can see an example with hexagons in the question [Drawing Hexagons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6128). I didn't do the work to control the size within Tikz, but it's straightforward to adapt the method described above.

Comment: Philippe, nice answer. I was wondering, can you change the color of the lines or their style (dashed, dotted, etc)? And another thing, what if you put two of these slightly overlapping each other, how do you make sure both lines/colors are easily visible? If you just overlap them as they are, the second one covers the first one. I tried a yshift but it doesn't work well. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: I've added options for the color and the shifting. Dotted or dashed lines won't work correctly because of how the patterns are made.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Brilliant, thanks. Yeah, well I've noticed... are the lines made of many shorter lines in sequence? Is that the reason?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, that's the reason. If you really want dashed hatching, you could clip to your shape some lines made with a for loop, but it's a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Nevermind, this one works great. Besides I've noticed that if I change some parameter in the preamble code (don't remember which), I can make them look like dashed.

Comment: This is a great post. When I ported the code on hatch lines (the second part of the answer) to a graph of mine, I noticed a strange behaviour that is fixed if I replace {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}  by {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}. Just for the record. I don't suppose it's worth opening a whole new thread...

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: what line of code do I have to modify to get north east lines?

Comment: But [don't try this with the circles example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232034/declaring-patterns-with-variables-in-tikz-understanding-the-effect-of-the-varia) ;).

Comment: Very good answer. Though for the color I would rather use the existing key `pattern color`, which can be used in the pattern with `\tikz@pattern@color`. You additionally need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. *Beware:* Do not forget to add `\tikz@pattern@color` in the list of variables. See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119711/115883) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the answer from Philippe Goutet to create a custom pattern in `pgfgantt` bars.
However, the hatching was off and did not align with the bar borders very well.
I ended up using the `mylines` example from http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=737 which worked great.
You can easily customize the hatching's spacing, line width and angle.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usetikzlibrary {patterns.meta}
\tikzdeclarepattern{
  name=mylines,
  parameters={
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/angle},
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width},
  },
  bounding box={
    (0,-0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width}) and
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},
     0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width})},
  tile size={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size})},
  tile transformation={rotate=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/angle}},
  defaults={
    size/.initial=5pt,
    angle/.initial=45,
    line width/.initial=.4pt,
}, code={
\draw [line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/line width}] (0,0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/pattern keys/size},0);
}, }

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
    \gantttitle{2022}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={preaction={fill, LimeGreen},pattern={mylines[size=5pt,line width=2.5pt,angle=45]},pattern color=NavyBlue}]{Work Package 1}{1}{12}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image: pgfgantt]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!