# Hatch Rectangle or Area in TikZ/pgf 3.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac

I just switched to TikZ 3.0 and was used to hatch rectangles similar to this thread

[Hatch a rectangle in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz)

actually the example given in the accepted answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54465/8042 was my favourite way. Nevertheless, since TikZ/pgf 3.0.0 the hatches look quite strange, cf. Chapter 60 (p. 674) in the most recent manual.

Does anybody know how to get the old `north west lines` back?

Comment: Which is the problem? I compiled the document posted in the answer you mentioned, but I don't see any issues.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting; i was at work at a Mac already running Mac OS Yosemite 10.10 and the lines are not rendered as solid lines but dashed (and that quite loosely dashed). When i tried to get a screenshot here at home, i noticed, that neither the manual nor my example pdf (synced via seafile) do have the issue on Mac OS Mavericks (on both OSes using Skim to display). Hopefully it's just Skim not being ready for Yosemite; I will post a screen shot tomorrow, just for completeness

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-TeX software performance

Comment: Yes, it definitely is. My answer was merely to emphasise that point. I first thought it would be related to the update of TikZ to 3.0, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Claudio postet his comment yesterday i tried to reproduce the error at home. I noticed, that the error seems to be related to the software/OS: On Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks with Skim everything looks fine, on 10.10 Yosemite Beta 1, also using Skim, it looks the following when opening the same PDF (compiled on Yosemite)

[image: Strange Hatch]

Noticing this, i think it's a rendering problem, maybe also related to the fact that Yosemite is still beta. It does not seem TeX/TikZ related to me.