# Tikz - Draw rectangle with dashed one side and hatching on the others

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern, tikz-path

I need to a scheme like this one:
[image]

The problem is, I have no idea how to do the dashed line on top of rectangle and the hatching in the left side and in the bottom.

Is it possible with Tikz?

Comment: definitely possible, you just need someone motivated enough to do it.... it'd be great if you could get that person started

Comment: You can use the patterns library by saying `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`. Then you create a path with `\pattern[pattern=north west lines] (x1,y1) -- (x2,y2) ... -- cycle` which gets filled with the hatching. The dashed lines you simply create with `\draw[dashed] (x1,y1) -- (x2,y2) -- ...` Here (x,y) are the coordinates of the corners. Just try it and when you run into problems, edit your question to the specific problem.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point for you. Start to modify it to your needs and if you run into problems, edit your question and comment under this answer, so I get a notification. Then I am going to help you further:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
    \pattern[pattern=north east lines] (0,0)--(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (0,2) -- (1,2);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: @Matsmath It's a starting point for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good starting point.

```
\documentclass{standalone}                                          

\usepackage{tikz}                                                   
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, decorations.pathreplacing, calc}          

\begin{document}                                                    

\renewcommand{\b}{10}                                               
\newcommand{\h}{5}                                                  
\renewcommand{\t}{.5}                                               

\begin{tikzpicture}                                                 
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);                                         
  \coordinate (E) at (\b,0);                                        
  \coordinate (En) at (\b,\t);                                      
  \coordinate (One) at (\t,\t);                                     
  \coordinate (Ne) at (\t,\h);                                      
  \coordinate (N) at (0,\h);                                        
  \coordinate (NE) at (N -| E);                                     
  \draw[thick, pattern=north east lines] (O) -- (E) -- (En) -- (One) -- (Ne) -- (N) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick] (En) -- (NE);                                        
  \draw[dashed] (Ne) -- (NE);                                       
  \draw[thick, decorate, decoration={brace, raise=20pt}] (NE) -- (E) node[midway, right=30pt] {text};                                               
  \draw[thick, decorate, decoration={brace, raise=20pt, mirror}] (O) -- (E) node[midway, below=30pt] {text}; 
\end{tikzpicture}                                                   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another starting point

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0)-|(3,.5)-|(0.5,2)-|cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (0,2)--(3,2);
    \draw (3,0)--(3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]