# Pattern background in table cell or minipage

Tags: tables, backgrounds

More than a code answer, I am asking for pointers. What packages should I look into to get something similar with the image? The hard part (I think) is the stripped background. The digit, then is just placement with white color. (btw, using XeLaTeX)

[image: My Goal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to point you to the `patterns` library of tikz. The following code and result could be a starter for you (BTW see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz) for similar question).

[image: pattern]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\draw[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=black] (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\node[color=white,scale=8] at (2,1) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems it is not possible to change a pattern line width. But one can look into the pgf patterns file (pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex), copy the pattern definition, and change the line width:

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{my horizontal lines}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{3pt}}% 
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{0.5pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

and change the code above to use this pattern name (my horizontal lines).

Comment: How to set linewidth? Trying \pgfsetlinewidth{50mm} with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: @Alberto I don't actually know, but you could try to make a bigger rectangle and then scale it down (just Q&D).

Comment: Completed your answer with line width info. May take some time before it is peer reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to obtain such a pattern background with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-grad,pst-text, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
    \psset{framesep=4pt, linewidth=0.4pt}
    \psframebox[framesep=-0.05pt, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Lavender!75, linecolor=LavenderBlush4]{\psframebox[fillstyle=hlines, hatchangle =0, hatchsep=1.5pt, hatchcolor=LavenderBlush4, linecolor=LavenderBlush4]{\hspace{0.6cm}%
        \pscharpath[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white]{\fontsize{120pt}{120pt}\selectfont\bfseries 4}}}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is similar possible with TikZ? I liked your solution very much (+1), but I'm not familiar with `postcripts` ...

Comment: The `postscript` is here for `auto-pst-pdf`, which enables compilation with `pdflatex`.  The pspicture environment would be OK with latex or xelatex. That said, with TikZ, I suppose yes, but I don't know it well – actually I only use `tikz-cd` for commutative diagrams, and I always found pstricks simpler to use. Doesn't the tikz code of the answer below do  more or less the same thing?

Comment: Answer with TikZ do almost the same, but the number is not outlined. I can reproduce your solution with TikZ, but without outlined number.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a specialist if there exists the equivalent of `\pscharpath`, which turns a character into a closed  path.

Comment: There is bidicontour (not Tikz, though), that I am already using. But in fact, not sure if the number path is required. Will try to apply the TIkz answer in my document and report soon.