# Hatch direction

Tags: tikz-styles, pattern

I want to modify the hatch lines direction marked in red of the next diagram:

[image]

It was obtained with the next code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,fit,matrix,arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\savestar\star
\renewcommand\star{{\scalerel*{\bigstar}{\savestar}}}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rsfso} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{mathtools}



% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=5pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=1.5pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north west lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }







\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (5.375cm and 1.5cm);
\draw (-5.375,-0.5) arc (180:360:5.375 and 1.5);
\draw (-5.375,0) -- ++(0,-0.5);
\draw (5.375,0) -- ++(0,-0.5);

\draw (0,0) ellipse (2.685cm and 0.75cm);
\draw (2.6,-0.2) arc (19:165:2.7 and 0.75);

\draw (1.5,0) -- (2.7,0);
\draw (-2.7,0) -- (-1.5,0);
\draw (0,0.75) -- (0,0.2);
\draw (0,-0.75) -- (0,-0.2);

\draw (1.7,0.6) -- (0.7,0.2);
\draw (1.7,-0.6) -- (0.7,-0.2);
\draw (-1.7,0.6) -- (-0.7,0.2);
\draw (-1.7,-0.6) -- (-0.7,-0.2);

\draw (0.8,0.7) -- (0.35,0.2);
\draw (0.8,-0.7) -- (0.35,-0.2);
\draw (-0.8,0.7) -- (-0.35,0.2);
\draw (-0.8,-0.7) -- (-0.35,-0.2);


\draw (2.4,0.3) -- (1.2,0.1);
\draw (2.4,-0.3) -- (1.2,-0.1);
\draw (-2.4,0.3) -- (-1.2,0.1);
\draw (-2.4,-0.3) -- (-1.2,-0.1);


\path (0,-7) -- (5,-7) node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,pos=0] (x1) {};


\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-7) -- (6,-7) node[pos=1.1,fill=white,circle]{$r$};

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-7) -- (0,-13) node[pos=1.1,circle]{$z(r,\theta)$};

\draw (2.685,-6.7) -- (5.375,-6.7) -- (5.375,-7.3) -- (2.685,-7.3) -- (2.685,-6.7);

\draw (-2.685,-6.7) -- (-5.375,-6.7) -- (-5.375,-7.3) -- (-2.685,-7.3) -- (-2.685,-6.7);

\draw (2.685,-5.3) -- (2.685,-8.7); % línea para ashurado
\draw (-2.685,-5.3) -- (-2.685,-8.7);

\draw (2.685,-9.3) -- (2.685,-10.7);%Linea auxiliar 1

\draw (-5.375,-10.3) -- (-5.375,-11.3); % Linea auxiliar 2

\draw[{Latex[length=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-10.1) -- (2.685,-10.1) node[above,pos=0.5,fill=white,circle]{$b$};% Cota 1

\draw[{Latex[length=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-10.8) -- (-5.375,-10.8) node[above,pos=0.5,fill=white,circle]{$a$};% Cota 2


\draw[dashed] (-2.685,-2.3) -- (-2.685,-4.7);
\draw[dashed] (2.685,-2.3) -- (2.685,-4.7);

\draw[dashed] (-5.375,-1.5) -- (-5.375,-5.9);
\draw[dashed] (5.375,-1.5) -- (5.375,-5.9);

\draw[pattern=custom north west lines, hatchspread=24pt, hatchcolor=black, draw=none] (2.1,-8.7) rectangle (2.685,-5.3);

\draw[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=25pt,hatchcolor=black,draw=none] (-2.1,-8.7) rectangle (-2.685,-5.3);

\draw[dashed] (-5.375,-8.1) -- (-5.375,-9.6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the hatch lines to something like "custom east lines", that is this direction . Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes with a pattern `custom horizontal lines` that is an analog of your pattern `custom north west lines`. I also simplified the upper part of your code by switching to 3d coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta,3d}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz/54465
% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=5pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=1.5pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom horizontal lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr 0.5\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{\dimexpr 0.5\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }







\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{74}{0} 
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
 \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5.375cm]; 
 \draw (-5.375,0) -- (-5.375,-1.8)
 arc(180:360:5.375cm) --(5.375,0);
 \draw[clip] (0,0) circle[radius=2.685cm];
 \draw (0,-1.6) circle[radius=2.685cm];
 \foreach \X in {0,22.5,...,337.5}
  {\draw (\X:2.685) -- (\X:1);}
\end{scope}


\path (0,-7) -- (5,-7) node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,pos=0] (x1) {};


\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-7) -- (6,-7) node[pos=1.1,fill=white,circle]{$r$};

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-7) -- (0,-13) node[pos=1.1,circle]{$z(r,\theta)$};

\draw (2.685,-6.7) -- (5.375,-6.7) -- (5.375,-7.3) -- (2.685,-7.3) -- (2.685,-6.7);

\draw (-2.685,-6.7) -- (-5.375,-6.7) -- (-5.375,-7.3) -- (-2.685,-7.3) -- (-2.685,-6.7);

\draw (2.685,-5.3) -- (2.685,-8.7); % línea para ashurado
\draw (-2.685,-5.3) -- (-2.685,-8.7);

\draw (2.685,-9.3) -- (2.685,-10.7);%Linea auxiliar 1

\draw (-5.375,-10.3) -- (-5.375,-11.3); % Linea auxiliar 2

\draw[{Latex[length=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-10.1) -- (2.685,-10.1) node[above,pos=0.5,fill=white,circle]{$b$};% Cota 1

\draw[{Latex[length=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-10.8) -- (-5.375,-10.8) node[above,pos=0.5,fill=white,circle]{$a$};% Cota 2


\draw[dashed] (-2.685,-2.3) -- (-2.685,-4.7);
\draw[dashed] (2.685,-2.3) -- (2.685,-4.7);

\draw[dashed] (-5.375,-1.5) -- (-5.375,-5.9);
\draw[dashed] (5.375,-1.5) -- (5.375,-5.9);

\path[pattern=custom horizontal lines, hatchspread=8pt, hatchcolor=black] (2.1,-8.7) rectangle (2.685,-5.3);

\path[pattern=custom horizontal lines,hatchspread=8pt,hatchcolor=black] (-2.1,-8.7) rectangle (-2.685,-5.3);

\draw[dashed] (-5.375,-8.1) -- (-5.375,-9.6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`custom north east lines` are even simple because you only need to exchange two coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta,3d}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz/54465
% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=5pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=1.5pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north east lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-0.15pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-0.15pt}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{\hatchshift}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }

% horizontal lines
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom horizontal lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr 0.5\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{\dimexpr 0.5\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }







\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{74}{0} 
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
 \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5.375cm]; 
 \draw (-5.375,0) -- (-5.375,-1.8)
 arc(180:360:5.375cm) --(5.375,0);
 \draw[clip] (0,0) circle[radius=2.685cm];
 \draw (0,-1.6) circle[radius=2.685cm];
 \foreach \X in {0,22.5,...,337.5}
  {\draw (\X:2.685) -- (\X:1);}
\end{scope}


\path (0,-7) -- (5,-7) node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,pos=0] (x1) {};


\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-7) -- (6,-7) node[pos=1.1,fill=white,circle]{$r$};

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-7) -- (0,-13) node[pos=1.1,circle]{$z(r,\theta)$};

\draw (2.685,-6.7) -- (5.375,-6.7) -- (5.375,-7.3) -- (2.685,-7.3) -- (2.685,-6.7);

\draw (-2.685,-6.7) -- (-5.375,-6.7) -- (-5.375,-7.3) -- (-2.685,-7.3) -- (-2.685,-6.7);

\draw (2.685,-5.3) -- (2.685,-8.7); % línea para ashurado
\draw (-2.685,-5.3) -- (-2.685,-8.7);

\draw (2.685,-9.3) -- (2.685,-10.7);%Linea auxiliar 1

\draw (-5.375,-10.3) -- (-5.375,-11.3); % Linea auxiliar 2

\draw[{Latex[length=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-10.1) -- (2.685,-10.1) node[above,pos=0.5,fill=white,circle]{$b$};% Cota 1

\draw[{Latex[length=2mm]}-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,-10.8) -- (-5.375,-10.8) node[above,pos=0.5,fill=white,circle]{$a$};% Cota 2


\draw[dashed] (-2.685,-2.3) -- (-2.685,-4.7);
\draw[dashed] (2.685,-2.3) -- (2.685,-4.7);

\draw[dashed] (-5.375,-1.5) -- (-5.375,-5.9);
\draw[dashed] (5.375,-1.5) -- (5.375,-5.9);

\path[pattern=custom north east lines, hatchspread=10pt, hatchcolor=black] (2.1,-8.7) rectangle (2.685,-5.3);

\path[pattern=custom north east lines,hatchspread=10pt,hatchcolor=black] (-2.1,-8.7) rectangle (-2.685,-5.3);

\draw[dashed] (-5.375,-8.1) -- (-5.375,-9.6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @marmot, I made a mistake. With the code I wrote I get a different diagonal hatching. I want to get the kind of diagonal hatching that I have posted in the figure. It is diagonal lines "/". Sorry for the confusions.

Comment: @Alfredo You already got the diagonal hatching in the code of your question. What is your question then about, i.e. what do you want us to do?

Comment: if you run my code you get a different hatch that is in the figure. Watch it carefully, is not the same. The question is: How can I obtain that hatch of the figure?.

Comment: @Alfredo I see. I added `custom north east lines`. BTW, if you got `custom north west lines` from some other post, could you perhaps consider indicating the source? Whoever wrote this pattern deserves some credit, I think.

Comment: the `custom north west lines` code was obtained from the answer of @Alain Matthes here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54464/hatch-a-rectangle-in-tikz/54465