Tikz patterns rendering incorrectly when viewing in adobe
When viewing my output in Tex studio the 45 deg line pattern renders as it should as shown here:

When viewing in Adobe or Sumatra I get the following:

Zooming out doesnt make it any better, only when zoomed in extrememly close do the lines render correctly.
I haven't had this issue with any other Tikz library and I am at a loss on what is going on. Others have had similar issues, but their solutions don't apply to my situation.
Here:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,arrows,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,math,shapes.misc, positioning, shapes.geometric, intersections, quotes, angles, positioning, patterns, patterns.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function = {
        h(\x) = sqrt((2*sin(2*pi*\x/0.02 r))^2);
    },
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        title=\large{\textbf{RMS Visualised}},
        title style={yshift=7mm,},
        xlabel={Time (s)},
        ylabel={Voltage (V)},
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin=0, xmax=.021,
        xtick={0,0.01,0.02},
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=2,
        },
        scaled x ticks=false,
        yticklabel=\empty, 
        xticklabel=\empty,
        ytick style={draw=none}, 
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        height=0.4\textwidth,
        scale=1,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)},
            anchor=west, right=1mm,
        },  
        every axis y label/.style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)},
            anchor=south, above=1mm,
        },
        samples = 100,
        axis line style = {-{Stealth[scale=1.0]}, thick}, %,
        every axis plot/.append style={thick},
        ]
        \addplot[color=green, domain=0:0.02]{h(\x)} node[above, pos=0.75] {$\sqrt{V^2}$};
        \draw[-, thick, color= violet] (axis cs:0,{2/sqrt(2)}) -- (axis cs:0.02,{2/sqrt(2)}) node[right] {$V_{_{\mathrm{RMS}}}$};
        \fill[pattern color=violet, fill opacity=1, pattern={Lines[angle=45, line width=0.8pt, distance= 2mm]}] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.02,{2/sqrt(2)}); 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


That's a viewer problem. Try others, like the FireFox browser. You might impact on it by >> slightly << changing some of the relevant parameters.

@MS-SPO I have tried FireFox and Chrome and the same issue arises. Just ran \fill[pattern color=violet, fill opacity=1, pattern={Lines[angle=45, line width=0.8pt, distance= 2mm]}] (0,0) rectangle (1,{2/sqrt(2)});  inside a Tikzpicture environment and the same issue arose

You may try to adopt this example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54471/42803 for your purpose.

Thanks for the reply. I did think about using macros, but I need this to fill under a function. I just dont have time to learn how to adjust that code for my situation. Thanks for your help anyway!
