# Changing density of pattern in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I was redrawing a picture with Ti*k*Z and here is the original:

[image: Screenshot]

I don't have any problems to draw this, but as you can see in my MWE, I've just scopped some areas to make manually a pattern which have the density which I want. But first, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={font=\tiny}]
            \draw[very thick] (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5);
                \fill[pattern=north east lines,very thick] (0,4.98) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4.98);
            \draw[very thick,fill=white] (.2,5) -- (.2,.2) -- (4.8,.2) -- (4.8,5);
            \draw[very thick] (.2,1) -- (4.8,1);
            \draw[very thick] (.4,5) -- (.4,1) -- (4.6,1) -- (4.6,5) to[bend left=30] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (.4,5) -- cycle;
                \draw[very thick] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.5,5);
                \begin{scope}
                    \clip[draw] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.5,5) -- cycle;
                    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,14}
                    {
                        \draw[xshift=4.5cm,yshift=5cm,xshift=-2cm,xshift=4*\x] (120:1) -- (-60:1);
                    }
                \end{scope}
    %       \fill[pattern=north west lines] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.55,5) -- cycle;
            \begin{scope}
                \clip[draw] (.4,1.2) -- (4.6,1.2) -- (4.6,1) -- (.4,1) -- cycle;
                \foreach \x in {1,2,...,70}
                {
                    \draw[xshift=2cm,yshift=1.1cm,xshift=-2cm,xshift=2*\x] (30:.5) -- (210:.5);
                }
            \end{scope}
            \draw[very thick] (.4,1.2) -- (4.6,1.2);
                \draw[very thick,fill=white] (2.2,.9) rectangle (2.8,1.3);
            \draw (2.2,1) -- (2.8,1);
            \draw (2.2,1.2) -- (2.8,1.2);
                    \draw[ultra thin,dash pattern={on 5pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (2.5,.5) --+ (0,5);
                \draw[<->] (.4,3.7) -- (4.6,3.7) node[midway,fill=white] {$\stackrel{d_a}{(2r_a)}$};
            \draw[ultra thick,<-] (2.5,5) --+ (0,2) node[left] {$P$};
                \draw (2.2,.9) --+ (0,-1.5);
                \draw (2.8,.9) --+ (0,-1.5);
            \draw[thick,<-] (2.2,-.4) --+ (-.7,0);
            \draw[thick,<-] (2.8,-.4) --+ (.7,0);
                \node[below=2] at (2.5,0) {$d_i$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

And now my question:

How can I change the predefined density of the patterns from the `tikzlibrary patterns` in generally (with some parameters, so that you have a usage like `… density=200 …` for example)?

P.S.: Not like here: [How to change the density of a pattern?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323858/how-to-change-the-density-of-a-pattern)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns

Comment: When you are saying not like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323858/how-to-change-the-density-of-a-pattern), which part of that answer do you dislike? Judging from @percusse's link and the pgfmanual, the only way to go seems to define your own pattern.

Comment: Perhaps see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119711/121799) in case you want to use the `pattern color` key.

Comment: @marmot: I would like to have a option where I can change the density of the pattern(s) which are from the ```tikzlibrary patterns```. P.S.: I already now for the color-key, thanks!

Comment: I guess you need to "redo" the patterns for this. The good news is that this will be rather straightforward: just copy the contents of the library and add some keys.

Comment: @marmot: Yes, I've already think about it, but I want something like this: ```\fill[pattern=STYLE,density=NUMBER] …```

Comment: Yes, but you can achieve this with keys. Just copy the file, rename e.g. `north east lines` to `flexible north east lines` and then add the keys. See e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427208/121799) and its answers to see how that works. Of course, you could just make your question here more specific and hope that someone does that. In general, I think that would be a rather nice and useful addition to the Ti*k*Z libraries (unless I am missing something).

Comment: @percusse Sorry for bugging you but do you know why the [Ti*k*Z libray patterns.meta](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207576/121799) didn't make it to the pgfmanual?

Comment: @marmot: Thank you, so I will do this alone. I'll just let the question open, maybe someone got an answer. I just turned 14 this year and I'm not doing (La)TeX very long, so that's the reason why I am asking a lot …

Comment: @marmot Mark should know. Probably it is not finished yet.

Comment: In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/1952, Jake proposes a pattern where it's possible to change line thickness and line distance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In his answer to [Pgfplots: how to fill the area under a curve with oblique lines (hatching) as a pattern?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29359/pgfplots-how-to-fill-the-area-under-a-curve-with-oblique-lines-hatching-as-a/29367#29367), Jake defines a `north east hatch` whit two parameters: hatch distance and hatch thickness. You can use this pattern and adjust these parameters to your taste.

Here you have an example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}

%See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/1952
\makeatletter
\tikzset{% customization of pattern 
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=5pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=5pt
        }
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{north east hatch}% name
    {\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}% below left
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}% above right
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={font=\tiny}]
    \draw[very thick] (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5);
   \fill[pattern=north east lines,very thick] (0,4.98) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4.98);
   \draw[very thick,fill=white] (.2,5) -- (.2,.2) -- (4.8,.2) -- (4.8,5);
   \draw[very thick] (.2,1) -- (4.8,1);
   \draw[very thick] (.4,5) -- (.4,1) -- (4.6,1) -- (4.6,5) to[bend left=30] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (.4,5) -- cycle;
   \draw[very thick] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.5,5);

   \pattern[pattern=north east hatch, hatch distance=3mm, hatch thickness=.5pt] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.5,5) -- cycle;

   \pattern[pattern=north east hatch, hatch distance=1mm, hatch thickness=.5pt] (.4,1.2) -- (4.6,1.2) -- (4.6,1) -- (.4,1) -- cycle;

   \draw[very thick] (.4,1.2) -- (4.6,1.2);
   \draw[very thick,fill=white] (2.2,.9) rectangle (2.8,1.3);
   \draw (2.2,1) -- (2.8,1);
   \draw (2.2,1.2) -- (2.8,1.2);
   \draw[ultra thin,dash pattern={on 5pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (2.5,.5) --+ (0,5);
   \draw[<->] (.4,3.7) -- (4.6,3.7) node[midway,fill=white] {$\stackrel{d_a}{(2r_a)}$};
   \draw[ultra thick,<-] (2.5,5) --+ (0,2) node[left] {$P$};
   \draw (2.2,.9) --+ (0,-1.5);
   \draw (2.8,.9) --+ (0,-1.5);
   \draw[thick,<-] (2.2,-.4) --+ (-.7,0);
   \draw[thick,<-] (2.8,-.4) --+ (.7,0);
   \node[below=2] at (2.5,0) {$d_i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**: This is *not* an answer, there are still things that need to get fixed. But this might be a starting point. If somebody else completes this in the meantime, I will be happy to delete this post. What I did was to copy some of the patterns from the pgf library patterns and started to make them more flexible. This works, to some extent.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\flex@pattern@density}
\newlength{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
\newlength{\flex@pattern@auxlength}
\newlength{\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo}
\tikzset{/tikz/.cd,
    pattern density/.code={\setlength\flex@pattern@density{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{1.1*#1}
    \setlength\flex@pattern@auxlength{\tmp pt}
    \setlength\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo{#1}
    \advance\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo by 0.1pt
    \typeout{\the\flex@pattern@density,\the\flex@pattern@auxlength}},
    pattern density=3pt,
    pattern line width/.code={\setlength\flex@pattern@linewidth{#1}},
    pattern line width=0.4pt,
}


\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth]{flexible horizontal lines}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{\flex@pattern@density}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{0.5pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth]{flexible vertical lines}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{100pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{100pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.5pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.5pt}{100pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo,\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth,\flex@pattern@auxlength]{flexible north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@auxlength}{\flex@pattern@auxlength}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{\flex@pattern@density}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo}{\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo,\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth,\flex@pattern@auxlength]{flexible north west lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@auxlength}{\flex@pattern@auxlength}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{\flex@pattern@density}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\flex@pattern@auxlengthtwo}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}


% Crossed lines in different directions

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth,\flex@pattern@auxlength,\tikz@pattern@color]{flexible grid}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@auxlength}{\flex@pattern@auxlength}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{\flex@pattern@density}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\flex@pattern@density}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth,\flex@pattern@auxlength,\tikz@pattern@color]{flexible crosshatch}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@auxlength}{\flex@pattern@auxlength}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\flex@pattern@density}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{\flex@pattern@density}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}


% Dotted regions

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth,\tikz@pattern@color]{flexible dots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{\flex@pattern@density}}%
{
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\flex@pattern@density,\flex@pattern@linewidth,\tikz@pattern@color]{flexible crosshatch dots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{2.5pt}{2.5pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\flex@pattern@density}{\flex@pattern@density}}%
{
  \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{1.5pt}{1.5pt}}{\flex@pattern@linewidth}
  \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={font=\tiny}]
            \draw[very thick] (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,5);
                \fill[pattern=flexible north east lines,pattern line
                width=0.8pt,pattern color=blue] (0,4.98) -- (0,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4.98);
            \draw[very thick,fill=white] (.2,5) -- (.2,.2) -- (4.8,.2) -- (4.8,5);
            \draw[very thick] (.2,1) -- (4.8,1);
            \draw[very thick] (.4,5) -- (.4,1) -- (4.6,1) -- (4.6,5) to[bend left=30] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (.4,5) -- cycle;
                \draw[very thick] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.5,5);
                \begin{scope}
                    \draw[pattern=flexible north west lines,pattern density=9pt] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.5,5) -- cycle;
%                     \foreach \x in {1,2,...,14}
%                     {
%                         \draw[xshift=4.5cm,yshift=5cm,xshift=-2cm,xshift=4*\x] (120:1) -- (-60:1);
%                     }
                \end{scope}
           \fill[pattern=north west lines] (2.5,5) to[bend right=30] (4.6,5) to[bend right=30] (2.55,5) -- cycle;
            \begin{scope}
                \draw[pattern=flexible north east lines,pattern color=red,
                pattern density=1pt,pattern line width=0.2pt] (.4,1.2) -- (4.6,1.2) -- (4.6,1) -- (.4,1) -- cycle;

            \end{scope}
            \draw[very thick] (.4,1.2) -- (4.6,1.2);
                \draw[very thick,fill=white] (2.2,.9) rectangle (2.8,1.3);
            \draw (2.2,1) -- (2.8,1);
            \draw (2.2,1.2) -- (2.8,1.2);
                    \draw[ultra thin,dash pattern={on 5pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (2.5,.5) --+ (0,5);
                \draw[<->] (.4,3.7) -- (4.6,3.7) node[midway,fill=white] {$\stackrel{d_a}{(2r_a)}$};
            \draw[ultra thick,<-] (2.5,5) --+ (0,2) node[left] {$P$};
                \draw (2.2,.9) --+ (0,-1.5);
                \draw (2.8,.9) --+ (0,-1.5);
            \draw[thick,<-] (2.2,-.4) --+ (-.7,0);
            \draw[thick,<-] (2.8,-.4) --+ (.7,0);
                \node[below=2] at (2.5,0) {$d_i$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The colors are just for fun, I was using [Ignasis answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119711/121799), and really could not make sense of the comment below it but may well be missing something.

There are several things that do not work or I am not sure about.

- If I choose the `pattern density` to be `8pt` instead of `9pt`, the lines are no longer equidistant. Most likely there is something obvious I am missing, but it is late here and I don't see it.
- Not sure if `pattern density` is a good name for that distance.
- Can't make the `pattern density` very small either.
- Only started to test the `flexible north west lines` and `flexible north east lines`, not the others.

Comment: This is nearly exactly what I want, but is it possible to put that all into ```pgfonlayer background```, so that the lines don't intersect the figure (it doesn't matter if the line color is set to black) and when just the fix is done, your answer will be marked as the best one! ;)

Comment: @current_user I think Ignasis answer is better than mine.