# crossing out arrow with tikz (with multiple crossing-out, not just one)

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am working on this "graph" in tikz, and I would like to know how I can add crossing-out (and not dashed) below the threshold `$\mu_A$` (from the beginning of the arrow, until the dot `$\mu_A$`), such as to explain that `$mu$` doesn't go below this threshold.
I put the picture of the code I get, associated with the code, and also a drawing of what I would like to get.
[image: objective]
[image: step2]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, thick, font=\footnotesize]    
% axis
\draw [dashed] [line width=1.2pt] (0,0) -- (3,0);  
\draw [line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex']  (3,0) --  coordinate (x axis) (10,0) [solid]; 

% time points
\draw (3,-4pt) coordinate (Ans)          -- (3,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_A$};
\draw (5,-4pt) coordinate (dev)      -- (5,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_{B}$};
\draw (7,-4pt) coordinate (Re) -- (7,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_{C}$};

% curly braces 
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
    (3,-2.5) coordinate (Ans_unten) -- (5,-2.5) coordinate (dev_unten); 
\node at (4,-3){$\triangle^{\text{opt}}$};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
    (dev_unten) -- (7,-2.5) coordinate (Re_unten); 
\node at (6,-3){$\triangle^{\text{impl}}$};

% vertical dotted lines
\draw[dotted] (Ans)          -- (Ans_unten);
\draw[dotted] (dev)      -- (dev_unten);
\draw[dotted] (Re) -- (Re_unten);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you describe the desired result in some more detail? If you could post an image (even a drawing made by hand) of the intended result, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always post *complete* documents and not just code snippets.

Below I present two possible options:

1. Using a simple `\foreach` loop to `\draw` the crossing-out lines:

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,patterns}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, thick, font=\footnotesize]    
   % axis
   \draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,0) -- (3,0) -- coordinate (x axis) (10,0);       

   % time points
   \draw (3,-4pt) coordinate (Ans)          -- (3,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_A$};
   \draw (5,-4pt) coordinate (dev)      -- (5,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_{B}$};
   \draw (7,-4pt) coordinate (Re) -- (7,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_{C}$};

   % curly braces
   \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
       (3,-2.5) coordinate (Ans_unten) -- (5,-2.5) coordinate (dev_unten); 
   \node at (4,-3){$\triangle^{\text{opt}}$};
   \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
       (dev_unten) -- (7,-2.5) coordinate (Re_unten); 
   \node at (6,-3){$\triangle^{\text{impl}}$};

   % vertical dotted lines
   \draw[dotted] (Ans)          -- (Ans_unten);
   \draw[dotted] (dev)      -- (dev_unten);
   \draw[dotted] (Re) -- (Re_unten);

   % the crossing-out lines
   \foreach \Step in {0,0.30,...,3}
     \draw[ultra thick] (\Step cm-7pt,7pt) -- (\Step cm+7pt,-7pt);
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Using a custom pattern (requires the `patterns` library):

   [image]

   The code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,patterns}

   % defining the new dimensions and parameters
   \newlength{\hatchspread}
   \newlength{\hatchthickness}
   \newlength{\hatchshift}
   \newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
   % declaring the keys in tikz
   \tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
            hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
            hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
            hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
   % setting the default values
   \tikzset{hatchspread=3pt,
            hatchthickness=0.4pt,
            hatchshift=0pt,% must be >= 0
            hatchcolor=black}
   % declaring the pattern
   \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
      {custom north west lines}% name
      {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
      {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
      {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
      {% shape description
       \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
       \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
       \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
       \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
         \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
         \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
       \fi
       \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
   %    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
       \pgfusepath{stroke}
      }

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, thick, font=\footnotesize]    
   % axis
   \draw[line width=1.2pt, ->, >=latex'](0,0) -- (3,0) -- coordinate (x axis) (10,0);       

   % time points
   \draw (3,-4pt) coordinate (Ans)          -- (3,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_A$};
   \draw (5,-4pt) coordinate (dev)      -- (5,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_{B}$};
   \draw (7,-4pt) coordinate (Re) -- (7,4pt) node[anchor=south] {$\mu_{C}$};

   % curly braces
   \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
       (3,-2.5) coordinate (Ans_unten) -- (5,-2.5) coordinate (dev_unten); 
   \node at (4,-3){$\triangle^{\text{opt}}$};
   \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt,mirror}] 
       (dev_unten) -- (7,-2.5) coordinate (Re_unten); 
   \node at (6,-3){$\triangle^{\text{impl}}$};

   % vertical dotted lines
   \draw[dotted] (Ans)          -- (Ans_unten);
   \draw[dotted] (dev)      -- (dev_unten);
   \draw[dotted] (Re) -- (Re_unten);

   % the crossing-out lines
   \fill[pattern=custom north west lines,hatchspread=8pt,hatchthickness=1pt,] 
     (0pt,7pt) rectangle (3,-7pt);
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   To define the new pattern, I used [`Philippe Goutet's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60234/3954) to [Custom and built in TikZ fill patterns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54358/3954).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment and advice. It is very hepful for me. I edited my post with a drawing of what I would like to get.

Comment: @Pauline Please see my updated answer.