# Framed environment with striped background

Tags: mdframed, framed

Dear friends, I have the following environment in a document:

[image: Environment 1]

which is produced the following code, except the dark green line, I kept it back for keeping my the *minimal* component in my MWE. `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[
   nobreak,
   middlelinewidth=.8pt,
   roundcorner=8pt
]{myframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
One line\\
Two lines\\
Three lines
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

I would like to add a striped background to it, something along the lines of:

[image: Environment 2]

It would be great if we could specify both thickness and colour of such bars. I am using `mdframed` at the moment, but a `tcolorbox` solution would also be welcoming. `:)` I think one could exploit the `patterns` library, but I am not sure on what to do here.

Any hints? `:)`

Comment: er, um, i don't see any stripes there.  but, unrelated to that, the "frame" isn't equally spaced on top and bottom, most likely because the last line doesn't have any descenders.  adding a `\strut` to the last line should solve that.

Comment: @barbara: you mean my second image? `:)` Sorry for the unequal spacing, I wrote a quick and dirty example! You are absolutely right, `\strut` does solve it; I can also add a `innerbottommargin` option to my `mdframed` environment and make things display as expected.

Comment: but you didn't say anything about the absence of stripes?  (the example may be quick & dirty, but i really did expect a "smudge" or two.)  or maybe it's just my monitor that's misbehaving?

Comment: @barbara: Oh I am so sorry, I had no idea on how to put the stripes in the first place, hence my poor example. `:)`

Comment: looks fancy :) is this for `arara v4` manual? :)

Comment: @cmhughes: Oh no, I've been spotted! `:)` I'm planning something along these lines, but a huge block with a striped background doesn't look so pleasant to the eye (it works with smaller chunks), so I have to use it carefully. `:)` By the way, we are making some huge progress on the tool, it's more stable than ever and with very cool features, I am sure you will love it. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below I give you some possibilities using both `mdframed` and `tcolorbox`:

The [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=3pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=0pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north east lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }
   
\newtcolorbox{stripbox}{
  enhanced,
  frame code={},
  interior code={
    \path[
      draw=green!80!black,
      rounded corners,
      pattern=custom north east lines,
      hatchspread=12pt,
      hatchthickness=4pt,
      hatchcolor=gray!20
    ]
    (interior.south east) rectangle (interior.north west);
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{stripbox}
test text
\end{stripbox}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

The [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,backgrounds}

% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=3pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=0pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north east lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr0.15pt+\hatchshift}{-0.15pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
%    \pgfsetdash{{1pt}{1pt}}{0pt}% dashing cannot work correctly in all situation this way
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }
   
\tikzset{
} 
    
\newmdenv[
  nobreak,
  roundcorner=6pt,
  linewidth=0pt,
  apptotikzsetting={
    \tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style=
      {
        draw=green!80!black,
        rounded corners,
        pattern=custom north east lines,
        hatchspread=12pt,
        hatchthickness=4pt,
        hatchcolor=gray!20
      }
    }
  }
]{stripbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{stripbox}
test text
\end{stripbox}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

### Remarks

- The customization for the pattern was done using **Philippe Goutet**'s code in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60234) to [Custom and built in TikZ fill patterns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54358).
- Since the code in the question includes the `nobreak` option I assumed in my answer that the environment is not required to admit page breaks; if this is not the case, the modifications required are not too big and can be easily made.

Comment: Gonzalo, your code is fantastic, thank you! Now I am in a very uncomfortable situation, I might replace `mdframed` by `tcolorbox`. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda If you give me some minutes I'll give you some `mdframed` code.

Comment: Oh please, do not worry! I have only one styled `mdframed` box, I can try converting it. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda `mdframed` option added :-)

Comment: @PauloCereda You are welcome!