# How to add patterns inside shapes bounded by curves?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

It is easy to use patterns for nice shapes like rectangle. How to fill an area  by patterns enclosed by some curves? For example I have trouble with adding pattern to the following between two arcs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-1,1) node (v1) {} circle (4.5);
\draw  (v1) circle (2.5);
\draw (-5.5,1) arc (180:360:1 and .25);
\draw (1.5,1) arc (180:360:1 and .25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a closed shape to use patterns or fill. Shapes bounded by curves can be converted or redrawn like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=horizontal lines] (-5.5,1) arc (180:360:1 and .25) arc (180:360:2.5) arc (180:360:1 and .25) arc (0:-180:4.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shape with pattern]

Comment: @CarLaTeX I do not understand what you mean!?

Comment: @CarLaTeX You meant to say `\path[pattern=horizontal lines] ...`? (`\fill` also does what you want it to do but this is in a way an accident.)

Comment: @marmot Yes, `\path`, lapsus!

Comment: Thanks @hpekristiansen. Is it possible to increase number of horizontal lines?

Comment: @C.F.G: Yes, but not easily. - see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (-1,1) node (v1) {} circle (4.5);
\draw  (v1) circle (2.5);

\fill[red](-5.5,1) arc (180:360:1 and .25)
arc(180:0:2.5)
arc (180:360:1 and .25)
arc (0:180:4.5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]