# TikZ: set the line width of the pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

Is there an easy way to control the line width (and inevitably the line distance) of a pattern decoration?

I want a uniform line hatching, e.g. red / blue, with line width, say 3mm.

BTW: *I need this for a large number of cells, so it would be good to use the patterns library to solve this, as opposed to drawing in manually.*

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Huge, 
Deco/.style={postaction={pattern=north west lines, 
%line width=6mm, ultra thick, % no effect
pattern color=blue}},
]
\node[Deco, fill=red, draw, minimum size=5cm]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's an example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60234/ (bottom half of answer) Edit: not for multiple colours, but for changing line width and separation

Comment: See the `patterns.meta` library which provides easy customization.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is to use the `patterns.meta` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Huge, 
Deco/.style={postaction={
pattern={
Lines[angle=-45, distance=6mm,  line width=3mm]% <--- !
},    pattern color=blue,
}},
]

\node[Deco, fill=red, draw, minimum size=5cm]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```