# How to fill 3 areas or more under a curve with different dashed colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I tried to use `tikz` and `pgfplots` packages in order to fill different areas under a curve with different colors.

The issue is in the script below. When I define the area's draw pattern for two first areas, it seems ok, as it gives me red and cyan dashed lines. I specify green as pattern color for the third one but the fill color remains cyan. Can anyone give me a hint to solve this. I want to have multiple filled areas with different filling colors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=4,
    xlabel={k'},
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    axis on top,
    legend style={legend cell align=right,legend plot pos=right}]

\addplot[name path=A,color=red,domain=0:4,samples=100] {1/(x+1)};


\path[name path=B] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

\addplot+[draw,pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=red]
fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=0:.25},
];

\addplot[pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=cyan,draw=blue,hatch distance=5pt, hatch thickness=0.5pt]
fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=0.25:0.5},
];


\addplot[pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=green,draw=blue,hatch distance=5pt, hatch thickness=0.5pt]
fill between[
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=0.5:0.9},
];


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lays in the definition of your custom pattern. With the link provided by [Ross in the comments below this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405443?noredirect=1#comment1010889_405505) one can modify your definition which then works perfectly fine.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        patterns,
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % the code bases was most likely borrowed from one of the following sources
    %     <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119711/95441>
    %     <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29367/95441>
    % with some adaptions found in
    %     <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60234/95441>
    % it now works perfectly fine
    \tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=10pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=2pt,
        hatch color/.store in=\hatchcolor,      % <-- added
        hatch color=black,                      % <-- added
    }
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[%
        \hatchdistance,%
        \hatchthickness,%
        \hatchcolor%                            % <-- added
            ]{flexible hatch}
    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}%        % <-- added
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,xmax=4,
        xlabel={k'},
        ymin=0,ymax=1,
        axis on top,
    ]
        \addplot [
            color=red,
            domain=0:4,
            smooth,                             % <-- (changed from `samples')
            name path=A,
        ] {1/(x+1)};

        \path [name path=B]
            (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
            (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

        \addplot+ [
            draw,
            pattern=flexible hatch,
            hatch color=red,                    % <-- changed from `pattern color'
        ] fill between [
            of=A and B,
            soft clip={domain=0:.25},
        ];

        \addplot [
            draw=blue,
            pattern=flexible hatch,
            hatch distance=5pt,
            hatch thickness=0.5pt,
            hatch color=cyan,
        ] fill between [
            of=A and B,
            soft clip={domain=0.25:0.5},
        ];

        \addplot [
            draw=blue,
            pattern=flexible hatch,
            hatch distance=5pt,
            hatch thickness=0.5pt,
            hatch color=green,
        ] fill between [
            of=A and B,
            soft clip={domain=0.5:0.9},
        ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns

Answer (score 2):

The solution to add `\tikz@pattern@color` to the list of variables. So replace

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
```

by

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness,\tikz@pattern@color]{flexible hatch}
```

The reason is that when you use a pattern with variables for the first time, a new fixed instance of the pattern is declared. This is to make pattern drawing efficient. A new pattern is only declared, when the variables change. But you haven't put `\tikz@pattern@color` in the list of variables, so it does not notice that you changed the color and uses the parameters with which it has been declared before.