# Shading to indicate the solution set to a system of two linear inequalities in x and y

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to show graphically the solution to the system of linear inequalities

```
\begin{equation*}

\begin{cases}
7x + 3y \geq 21 \\
-x + 3y < -3
\end{cases}
.
\end{equation*}
```

There are some modifications that I want to the display. First, I use `pattern=north east lines` for the solution set to `7x + 3y \geq 21`.  The lines are too close. I do not want the boundary. Second, I get an error when I tried to compile the code with `pattern=south east lines`. Third, I do not want these lines indicating the solution sets to interfere with the tick marks.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\bf Algebra 2}\end{center}\vskip0.3in

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-11,xmax=11,
    ymin=-11,ymax=11,
    restrict y to domain=-11:11,
    xtick={},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]


\coordinate (P) at (-9/7,10);
\coordinate (Q) at (10,10);
\coordinate (R) at (10,-10);
\coordinate (S) at (51/7,-10);

\draw[pattern=north east lines] (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- (S);


\coordinate (P1) at (-10,-13/3);
\coordinate (Q1) at (10,7/3);
\coordinate (R1) at (10,-10);
\coordinate (S1) at (-10,-10);

%\draw[pattern=south east lines] (P1) -- (Q1) -- (R1) -- (S1);

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-1.5:7.5,blue] {(-7/3)*x + 7};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:10,dashed,green] {(1/3)*x -1};

\node[anchor=north west] at (axis description cs:1,0.5) {$x$};
\node[anchor=north west] at (axis description cs:0.5,1) {$y$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't really like this, but I think this is what you asked for:

[image]

### Notes:

- Patterns are not easily changeable. I have used the code form [Can I control the 'density' of a pattern in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29808/can-i-control-the-density-of-a-pattern-in-tikz) to allow one to change the spacing between the lines.  The density of the lines below can be changed via `line space=<dimen>`.
- The border along the pattern was disabled via `draw=none` option.
- Adding `axis on top` option allows the axis and tick labels to be on top.
- There is no `south east lines` pattern, but there is a `north west lines` . I have applied the `my north west lines` as it was desired to alter the spacing between the lines.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29808/can-i-control-the-density-of-a-pattern-in-tikz
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\LineSpace]{my north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}%
{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\LineSpace]{my north west lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}%
{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\LineSpace}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}{-0.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\newdimen\LineSpace
\tikzset{
    line space/.code={\LineSpace=#1},
    line space=3pt
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\bf Algebra 2}\end{center}\vskip0.3in

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-11,xmax=11,
    ymin=-11,ymax=11,
    restrict y to domain=-11:11,
    xtick={},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
    axis on top,
]


\coordinate (P) at (-9/7,10);
\coordinate (Q) at (10,10);
\coordinate (R) at (10,-10);
\coordinate (S) at (51/7,-10);

%% Adjust density of the lines by changing the `line space=` value.
\draw[pattern=my north west lines, draw=none, line space=10pt] (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- (S);


\coordinate (P1) at (-10,-13/3);
\coordinate (Q1) at (10,7/3);
\coordinate (R1) at (10,-10);
\coordinate (S1) at (-10,-10);

%\draw[pattern=south east lines] (P1) -- (Q1) -- (R1) -- (S1);

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-1.5:7.5,blue, ultra thick] {(-7/3)*x + 7};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-10:10.4,dashed,orange, thick] {(1/3)*x -1};

\node[anchor=north west] at (axis description cs:1,0.5) {$x$};
\node[anchor=north west] at (axis description cs:0.5,1) {$y$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that you removed the boundary to the `north east` lines. That is nice. The lines are too densely packed.  Is there a better way to shade than using `patterns` or using `north east` and `north west` options in patterns?

Comment: I like that the arrowheads on the blue line are outside the shading.  I defined the domain of the blue line so that the highest point on it would be (-1.5, 10), but the arrowhead is distinctly above 10.  How did this happen?  I like the way it looks, though.  I would like to get the orange line to extend past the (invisible) line `x=10` just as much.

Comment: @user74973: Have adjust the density of the lines. Play around with with `line space=` parameter to get the desired results. Also extended the domain of the orange line to get the arrow past the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for adding the comment about removing the border along the pattern via `draw=none`.

Comment: By the way, I added `circle,inner sep=1.5pt` to the options for `ticklabel style=`.  The display looks much better with less white space in the mesh of hatching.

Comment: This is really picky ... but noticeable.  Your display seems to have the `north east` and `north west` lines below the `grid`.  When I compile your code, the `north east` and `north west` lines are drawn above the `grid`, which is distracting. How do I get these hatching lines above the grid?

Comment: @user74973: I suspect one of your packages are out of date. I am using the latest versions of the pacakges of the TeXLive2014.