# How do I create a "flashcards" document with a crosshatch background pattern to reduce transverse legibility?

Tags: backgrounds, flashcards, contour

I've been using flashcards a lot, via the ["flashcards" package](https://ctan.org/pkg/flashcards?lang=en) of Alexander Budge. Usually I print them on card stock but sometimes this can be inconvenient, for example most home-office duplex printers cannot print duplex on card stock. Aside from making it easier to shuffle and manipulate the cards, card stock is generally useful so that the text on the reverse of each card is not visible from the front.

I would like to try printing flashcards on ordinary printer paper, but with some kind of pattern on each side to make it more difficult to see what is written on the reverse of the card. This would be similar to the crosshatch pattern inside a "security envelope".

At the same time, I want the background pattern to avoid the text on each card, so that the text remains legible from the front. I am thinking about something like the last example in [this underlining tutorial](https://alexwlchan.net/2017/10/latex-underlines/).

I wonder if someone has done this, or is interested in coding up an example that I can add as a `\input` at the top of my flashcards documents.

Comment: ! noitseuq gnitseretni  <- -The last option combined with contour would certainly be gnisufnoc backwards Also many "cheap" heavyweight recycled papers would add to the effect.

Comment: I think generally if text is obscured by a random background sufficient to obscure reverse reading it may becomes so much less readable from the front, getting a fine balance would require some experimentation based on different "stock", anyway in order to stimulate ideas I will offer this weeks bounty.

Comment: @KJO an alternative way to attract more attention is for the OP, or possibly you, to add an MWE to the question.

Comment: Another way to possibly make the text stand out from the pattern, than the one I showed,  could be using a high opacity (eg. 1) and then just make the text white

Comment: Try Hilbert curves....

Comment: @JPi good idea, may be worth a shot to see if OP likes them or Sierpiński  however with regular fractal patterns the viewer may become so mesmerised following the patterns that they forget to answer the question :-)

Comment: Thank everyone for the examples and hard work and bounty and everything. For "crosshatch" I was thinking something [like a square grid, rotated 45 degrees](https://i.imgur.com/Xb0qbjV.gif). Also, I wanted the contour to be used as a white mask, as in the underlining tutorial, rather than the white box you get with colorbox. So basically all the text should be rendered over the background in thick white, and then again in the original black, so that the black text has a white "halo" around it. That was the idea at least. I may try to get a MWE later this week if I have time.

Comment: @Metamorphic I think I added what you wanted now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest using the `background` and `tikz` packages, from `tik` you can play around with designing your own patterns if you don't like the [existing ones](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114646/where-is-the-pattern-list-gallery-for-pgfplots).

Edit

use `colorbox` to remove the pattern from the text:

original again

Here I have stolen the example given in the flashcards documentation, and inserted a background:

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}

%The notable stuff starts here
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\backgroundsetup{%
  opacity=.2,    %% Play with this to increase/decrease readability
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \fill[pattern = crosshatch] (-50,-50) rectangle (50,50);    %% yshift and xshift for example only
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
%%%%%%      And ends here


\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{\colorbox{white}{Norm on a Linear Space} \\ \colorbox{white}{Normed Space} }

    A real-valued function $||x||$ defined on a linear space $X$, where15$x \in X$, is said to be a \emph{norm on} $X$ if
\smallskip
\begin{description}
\item [Positivity]            $||x|| \geq 0$,
\item [Triangle Inequality]   $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \:  ||x||$,
$\alpha$ an arbitrary scalar,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $||x|| = 0$ if and only if $x=0$,
\end{description}
\smallskip
$x$ and $y$ are arbitrary points in $X$.
\medskip
linear/vector space with a norm is called a \emph{normed space}.
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
$X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} on $X$ is
a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ a scalar,
denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies the following properties:
\medskip
\begin{description}
\item [Additivity]            $(x+y,z) = (x,z) + (y,z)$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $(\alpha \: x, y) = \alpha (x,y)$,
\item [Symmetry]              $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $(x,x) > 0$, when $x\neq0$.
\end{description}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Linear Transformation/Operator}
    Atransformation $L$ of (operator on) a linear space $X$ into a linear
    space $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have the same scalar field, is said to be
    a \emph{linear transformation (operator)} if
    \medskip
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $L(\alpha x) = \alpha L(x), \forall x\in X$ and $\forall$
            scalars $\alpha$, and
        \item $L(x_1 + x_2) = L(x_1) + L(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$.5
\end{enumerate}
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

## Edit

If you really want a morie pattern This should work, note however that the pattern will not be the same on all cards. This really makes it necessary to put white boxes on the text. You can change the density and location of the circles to change the patterns

```
\backgroundsetup{%
  color =black,  % play around
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \foreach \i in {1.5,2,...,30}
      {
      \draw (8,8) circle (\i);
      \draw (8,-8) circle (\i);
      \draw (-8,8) circle (\i);
      \draw (-8,-8) circle (\i);
  }
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
```

[image]

## Edit 2

Now an ellipse based pattern with the inkeating patterns removed outside the cards! And the pattern is more or less the same on all cards ;-)

```
\backgroundsetup{%
  color =black,  % play around
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \foreach \i in {10.1,10.2,...,150}
      {
      \draw (50,-50)  ellipse ({\i}  and 200);
      \draw (-50,-50) ellipse ({\i}  and 200);
  }
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (-6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (20,-20) rectangle (6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (-20,20) rectangle (20,11.2);
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (20,-12);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
}
```

[image]
You can also do all sorts of fun stuff, moving the ellipses so they don't align vertically and thus angle the pattern! a close up!

I still strongly suggest whiteboxing the actual text

[image]

## Edit

Heres one with a grey pattern and a outlined text

the text got outlined by using `\contour{color}` from the `contour` package

[image]

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% these might be important
  angle=0,       %% these might be important
  opacity=1.,    %% these might be important
  color =black,  %% these might be important
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \foreach \i in {10.1,10.2,...,150}
      {
    %  \draw (8,8) circle (\i);
    %  \draw (8,-8) circle (\i);
    %  \draw (-8,8) circle (\i);
    %  \draw (-8,-8) circle (\i);
    \draw[thick,opacity=0.2] (50,-50)  ellipse ({\i}  and 200);
    \draw[thick,opacity=0.2] (-50,-50) ellipse ({\i}  and 200);
  }
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (-6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (20,-20) rectangle (6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (-20,20) rectangle (20,11.2);
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (20,-12);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{\colorbox{white}{Norm on a Linear Space} \\ \contour{black}{\textcolor{white}{Normed Space $mathcheck$} }}
    A real-valued function $||x||$ defined on a linear space $X$, where15$x \in X$, is said to be a \emph{norm on} $X$ if
\smallskip
\begin{description}
\item [Positivity]            $||x|| \geq 0$,
\item [Triangle Inequality]   $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \:  ||x||$,
$\alpha$ an arbitrary scalar,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $||x|| = 0$ if and only if $x=0$,
\end{description}
\smallskip
$x$ and $y$ are arbitrary points in $X$.
\medskip
linear/vector space with a norm is called a \emph{normed space}.
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
$X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} on $X$ is
a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ a scalar,
denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies the following properties:
\medskip
\begin{description}
\item [Additivity]            $(x+y,z) = (x,z) + (y,z)$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $(\alpha \: x, y) = \alpha (x,y)$,
\item [Symmetry]              $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $(x,x) > 0$, when $x\neq0$.
\end{description}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Linear Transformation/Operator}
    Atransformation $L$ of (operator on) a linear space $X$ into a linear
    space $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have the same scalar field, is said to be
    a \emph{linear transformation (operator)} if
    \medskip
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $L(\alpha x) = \alpha L(x), \forall x\in X$ and $\forall$
            scalars $\alpha$, and
        \item $L(x_1 + x_2) = L(x_1) + L(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$.5
\end{enumerate}
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

I think you are asking for this:
[image]
Note that you need the `\contour{black}{\color{white} text here}` around all text.

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% these might be important
  angle=0,       %% these might be important
  opacity=1.,    %% these might be important
  color =black,  %% these might be important
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

          \fill[opacity=0.2,pattern=crosshatch] (-50,-50) rectangle (50,50);
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (-6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (20,-20) rectangle (6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (-20,20) rectangle (20,11.2);
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (20,-12);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{\contour{black}{\textcolor{white}{Functional Analysis}}}
\color{white}
\begin{flashcard}[\contour{black}{\textcolor{white}{Definition}}]{\contour{black}{\textcolor{white}{Norm on a Linear Space}} \\ \contour{black}{\textcolor{white}{Normed Space $mathcheck$ }}}
    A real-valued function $||x||$ defined on a linear space $X$, where15$x \in X$, is said to be a \emph{norm on} $X$ if
\smallskip
\begin{description}
\item [Positivity]            $||x|| \geq 0$,
\item [Triangle Inequality]   $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \:  ||x||$,
$\alpha$ an arbitrary scalar,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $||x|| = 0$ if and only if $x=0$,
\end{description}
\smallskip
$x$ and $y$ are arbitrary points in $X$.
\medskip
linear/vector space with a norm is called a \emph{normed space}.
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
$X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} on $X$ is
a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ a scalar,
denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies the following properties:
\medskip
\begin{description}
\item [Additivity]            $(x+y,z) = (x,z) + (y,z)$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $(\alpha \: x, y) = \alpha (x,y)$,
\item [Symmetry]              $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $(x,x) > 0$, when $x\neq0$.
\end{description}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Linear Transformation/Operator}
    Atransformation $L$ of (operator on) a linear space $X$ into a linear
    space $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have the same scalar field, is said to be
    a \emph{linear transformation (operator)} if
    \medskip
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $L(\alpha x) = \alpha L(x), \forall x\in X$ and $\forall$
            scalars $\alpha$, and
        \item $L(x_1 + x_2) = L(x_1) + L(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$.5
\end{enumerate}
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

## Edit

If I misunderstood your comment, this might be what you ment;

[image]

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% these might be important
  angle=0,       %% these might be important
  opacity=1.,    %% these might be important
  color =black,  %% these might be important
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \fill[opacity=0.2,pattern=crosshatch] (-50,-50) rectangle (50,50);
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (-6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (20,-20) rectangle (6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (-20,20) rectangle (20,11.2);
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (20,-12);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{\contour{white}{Functional Analysis}}
\begin{flashcard}[\contour{white}{Definition}]{\contour{white}{Norm on a Linear Space} \\ \contour{white}{Normed Space $mathcheck$ }}
    A real-valued function $||x||$ defined on a linear space $X$, where15$x \in X$, is said to be a \emph{norm on} $X$ if
\smallskip
\begin{description}
\item [Positivity]            $||x|| \geq 0$,
\item [Triangle Inequality]   $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \:  ||x||$,
$\alpha$ an arbitrary scalar,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $||x|| = 0$ if and only if $x=0$,
\end{description}
\smallskip
$x$ and $y$ are arbitrary points in $X$.
\medskip
linear/vector space with a norm is called a \emph{normed space}.
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
$X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} on $X$ is
a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ a scalar,
denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies the following properties:
\medskip
\begin{description}
\item [Additivity]            $(x+y,z) = (x,z) + (y,z)$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $(\alpha \: x, y) = \alpha (x,y)$,
\item [Symmetry]              $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $(x,x) > 0$, when $x\neq0$.
\end{description}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Linear Transformation/Operator}
    Atransformation $L$ of (operator on) a linear space $X$ into a linear
    space $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have the same scalar field, is said to be
    a \emph{linear transformation (operator)} if
    \medskip
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $L(\alpha x) = \alpha L(x), \forall x\in X$ and $\forall$
            scalars $\alpha$, and
        \item $L(x_1 + x_2) = L(x_1) + L(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$.5
\end{enumerate}
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

## A last one for KJO

So this one is a bit more customizable (just change the spacing in the tikz loop). note that I have again only thrown contours on the first card (but the command is copy pasteable)

[image]

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc}

\backgroundsetup{%
  scale=1,       %% these might be important
  angle=0,       %% these might be important
  opacity=1.,    %% these might be important
  color =black,  %% these might be important
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%         \foreach \i in {10.1,10.2,...,150}
          \foreach \i in {-50,-49.5,...,50}
      {

      \draw[thick,opacity=0.75]  (-20,\i) -- (20,{\i+40});
      \draw[thick,opacity=0.75]  (-20,{\i+40}) -- (20,\i);
  }
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (-6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (20,-20) rectangle (6.5,20);
  \fill[white] (-20,20) rectangle (20,11.2);
  \fill[white] (-20,-20) rectangle (20,-12);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}



\cardfrontfoot{\contour{white}{Functional Analysis}}
\begin{flashcard}[\contour{white}{Definition}]{\contour{white}{Norm on a Linear Space} \\ \contour{white}{Normed Space $mathcheck$ }}
    A real-valued function $||x||$ defined on a linear space $X$, where15$x \in X$, is said to be a \emph{norm on} $X$ if
\smallskip
\begin{description}
\item [Positivity]            $||x|| \geq 0$,
\item [Triangle Inequality]   $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \:  ||x||$,
$\alpha$ an arbitrary scalar,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $||x|| = 0$ if and only if $x=0$,
\end{description}
\smallskip
$x$ and $y$ are arbitrary points in $X$.
\medskip
linear/vector space with a norm is called a \emph{normed space}.
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}
$X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} on $X$ is
a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ a scalar,
denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies the following properties:
\medskip
\begin{description}
\item [Additivity]            $(x+y,z) = (x,z) + (y,z)$,
\item [Homogeneity]           $(\alpha \: x, y) = \alpha (x,y)$,
\item [Symmetry]              $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $(x,x) > 0$, when $x\neq0$.
\end{description}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Linear Transformation/Operator}
    Atransformation $L$ of (operator on) a linear space $X$ into a linear
    space $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ have the same scalar field, is said to be
    a \emph{linear transformation (operator)} if
    \medskip
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $L(\alpha x) = \alpha L(x), \forall x\in X$ and $\forall$
            scalars $\alpha$, and
        \item $L(x_1 + x_2) = L(x_1) + L(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$.5
\end{enumerate}
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice Tones, What may be "desirable" by OP is actually what most consider undesirable moiré patterns such as we see in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369119/halftone-screens-with-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @KJO If you move the circles further apart and denser the patterns will become more obvious but at the cost of ink and the readability of  "non whiteboxed text"

Comment: Nice adjustment, the ink issue could be minimised by confining to a smaller area around the text, which allows for closer spacing ?

Comment: @KJO Yes, give me a second (I want to tr using ellipses for the pattern, to get a more uniform result through the cards)

Comment: @KJO Besides restricting where the ink goes, you can also turn the opacity down, so the pattern is grey instead of black That needs to be done on the ellipses, not the background package. Otherwise the white boxes become seethrough

Comment: Costing me a fortune in pay per print :-)  not to mention the quart of ink :-) The tone needs to go GREYish behind Black letters otherwise I can still read from the reverse :-( what about an outline font ?

Comment: @KJO The tone is grey now, I'm not sure if i think the outlined font actually helps or made it worse (the $mathcheck$ was just to check if it would outline math)

Comment: That's good, suggest for now we await OP comments.

Comment: @KJO thanks ;-)

Comment: I added a comment on my original question, I don't know if anyone got pinged by that. Thanks again.

Comment: I thought OP means `\contour{white}{\textcolor{black}`?? Also `\contourlength{1pt}` looks nicer

Comment: @Symbol1 I think you where right in that, (That's what i did previously on some of the text, so I thought OP had seen it)

Comment: Certainly your last variant seems closest to edited question request, however in my opinion weak grey makes it too plain to see through without the back to back overlay Actually text on each side gets masked when both recto-verso and 180 aligned. So taking ALL into account I personally would use a small black grided area (saves ink)  with white contour around darkish outline lettering with that combination on cheap paper I find it does mask readability from the obverse more than enough.

Comment: @KJO do you mean what would happen if the opacity in the tikz `fill` command was set to one? Or do you want to use tha pattern in a smaller area of the paper?

Comment: I personally would only pattern a small enough area for slightly bigger than the larger sides content (carbon saving) then all ink can be "say" 75 % density again saving ink. The contrast on readers side only needs to be the outline of the glyphs

Comment: @KJO while not smaller (although it mostly fills within the card) The density is much lower, and can easily be adjusted by changing `\foreach \i  in {-50,-49.5,...,50}` to something with a larger spacing

Comment: Thank you indeed! The last example is exactly what I wanted. I notice it is surprisingly hard to read the text even from the front, but this may be desirable, for example if there are multiple items that need to be learned separately, then you can avoid reading the wrong one by reflex. Anyway I will try to report back when I get a chance to use this. Maybe it will save us a lot of money in card stock.

Comment: @Metamorphic if you change the `contourlength` to something greater than `1pt` it might become easier to read

Answer (score 3):

Here is my proposal of Moiré patterns.
I suppose only the secrete side needs protection,
so I put the pattern on the title side.

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}

    \cardfrontstyle[\large\sffamily\slshape]{headings}
    \makeatletter
    \def\flashcards@flush{
        \tikzhandler\vskip-\baselineskip\flashcards@flushfronts
        \flashcards@flushbacks
    }
    \def\tikzhandler{%
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page),opacity=.2]{
            \clip(-6,-11)rectangle(6,11);
            \foreach\j in{0,36,...,179}{
                \draw[rotate=\j,dash pattern={on1off3on2off4},line width=.6]
                    foreach\i in{-12,-11.9,...,12}{
                        (\i,-20)--(\i,20)
                    }
                ;
            }
        }%
    }

\begin{document}

    \cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}
    \begin{flashcard}[Definition]
        {\lipsum[1][1]}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{flashcard}
    \begin{flashcard}[Definition]
        {\lipsum[2][1]}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{flashcard}
    \begin{flashcard}[Definition]
        {\lipsum[3][1]}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### What can be seen form the title side (simulation)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
        \path(current page)node[xscale=-1]{\includegraphics[page=2]{490863.pdf}};
        \fill[white,opacity=.8] % this is the paper itself, adjust its opacity
            (current page.south west)rectangle(current page.north east);
        \path(current page)node{\includegraphics[page=1]{490863.pdf}};
    }
\end{document}
```

P.S. I am using lorem ipsum as secret text.
If the secret text is something meaningful,
it is more likely that it could be recognized.